# Trying to make my alarm manager alarm clock, survive force closing the app

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager

How do I make my alarm manager alarms that are set, not get erased after clearing all my running apps from memory.

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear exactly what you mean by "clearing all my running apps from memory". If you mean some sort of "clear all" option from the overview screen, last I checked, that does not affect `AlarmManager`. However, there certainly are things that *can* affect `AlarmManager` alarms, such as "Force Stop" in Settings and some device-specific "task manager" apps.

For those, your only viable option is to save your alarm information somewhere (file, `SharedPrefererences`, SQLite, Web service, etc.), and re-establish your `AlarmManager` alarms the next time your apps runs.

Comment: I am talking about when you hit the recent apps button, and swipe up to close the app, or hit close all. This gets rid of the alarm that is internally set. The little alarm icon at the top also disappears.

Comment: I just retried it, and they are not being removed anymore. I don't know what happened. But I am noticing when I relaunch my app in the emulator, that is clearing the internal alarm that are set, is that normal? The one set with alarmMgr?.setAlarmClock()